# grouping in rdlc report file

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a report with name and date of presentation. And currently rdlc report is generating it ion this way:

```
 FirstName    lastName    date
 =====================================
  X             A          12-Apr
  Y             B          12-Apr
  Z             C          12-Apr
  X1            A1         13-Apr
  Y1            B1         13-Apr
  Z1            C1         14-Apr
```

But I actually want it to be grouped with date. i want it to be like this

```
 Date: 12-Apr

 FirstName    lastName  
 ======================
  X             A         
  Y             B         
  Z             C          

 Date: 13-Apr

 FirstName    lastName  
 =======================
  X1             A1       
  Y1             B1  


 Date: 14-Apr

 FirstName    lastName  
 =======================
  Z1            C1
```

I am generating this report from dataset which contains values like this:

```
 FirstName    lastName    date
 =====================================
  X             A          12-Apr
  Y             B          12-Apr
  Z             C          12-Apr
  X1            A1         13-Apr
  Y1            B1         13-Apr
  Z1            C1         14-Apr
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? [Microsoft has some documentation about grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs) that may answer your question...

Comment: I looked for methods but not at all sure how I should start with this kind of grouping.

Comment: That page, and the pages it links to, has all of the information on grouping in SSRS/RDLC. There are links to tutorials, example code, everything. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services.

Comment: don't include the DATE in your Detail. Instead group by the DATE first and only include first and last name in detail